# what's the ideal way to deal with countries as a property on an object in mongoose (mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a property called `country` on a `jobSchema` it is a required string.

Basically just gets the iso-2 letter code (ie: US, NZ or whatever)...and that's what gets saved in the database for the object's `country` property.

However I have a countries.json file on the filesystem that contains an object containing full name (ie: United States) and lat/long coordinates.

```
{
    "name": "United States",
    "iso2": "US",
    "lat": "37.09024",
    "lng": "-95.712891"
}
```

I don't really need any crud interface for this. So I've built an API outside of the database to just map the "US" string from the db to the file object.

However, this is proving to be a bit of a PITA.

What is a good way to handle this?

Should I just store this full country object in the db and leave it at that? This seems the easiest route, except of a country definition changes, then I will have all this stale data littered across my mongo db wherever this data was saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Mongoose [**Population**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

> Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified
>   paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s).

You could begin by modifying the `"iso2"` property of this country object to an `_id` (since iso codes are unique for each country) and save the modified object in your db. Next is to create a new Mongoose schema for it that you can reference in your jobSchema. For example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

// Job Schema
var jobSchema = Schema({
    name    : String, 
    country : { type: String, ref: 'Country' }  // To be populated
});

var countrySchema = Schema({
    _id   : String,
    name  : String,    
    lat   : Number,
    lng   : Number
});

var Country  = mongoose.model('Country', countrySchema);
var Job      = mongoose.model('Job', jobSchema);
```

The `ref` option is what tells Mongoose which model to use during population, in your case the `Country` model. The `country` property of the `Job` model is declared as a `String`, the same type as the `_id` used in the `countrySchema`. It is important to match the type of `_id` to the type of `ref`.

To see how population works, just call the populate method on the `Job` model query and you will get the country field in the documents populated:

```
Job.find().populate('country').exec(function (error, jobs) {
   // ...
});
```